# Android Text inside of ToggleButton wont center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very unusual issue; I have a few ToggleButtons inside of a linear layout stacked horizontally. The text inside (textOn, textOff) of the buttons isn't centering, and after playing a bit with paddingLeft, I found that 15% of of each button on the right hand side is something of a 'dead area', meaning the text is wrapping when it hits it -- this would explain why it's not centering properly.

Here's the XML:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">           
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:weightSum="1.5"
            android:background="#0094d2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/off_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textOn="Button On"
                android:textOff="Button Off"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_states"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/off_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textOn="Button On"
                android:textOff="Button Off"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_states"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/off_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textOn="Button On"
                android:textOff="Button Off"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_states"/>                  
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:background="#999999" android:layout_height="1dip" android:id="@+id/divider" android:layout_below="@+id/buttons" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:divider="#cccccc"
                android:dividerHeight="1dip"                    
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
                android:fadingEdge="none"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[Link to Image, I'm too new so I can't add images yet ><](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUjbe.png)

I've tried setting the gravity in the layout and buttons to center_horizontal as well.. obviously, it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: and this too each ToggleButton:
android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied/pasted into eclipse and got:

[image]

I dont have your drawables, so cant look at them but i think that is your issue. Are you using 9 patch graphics for your button, if not have a look at this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: I am using 9 patch graphics, and you're right... it does have something to do with this. I will post my buttons Monday, and play around with them myself to see if i can get around this problem.

Comment: I uploaded my toggle buttons here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/iudpn.png) 

The top two are the 9patch files, and the bottom 2 are the normal files. It has to have something to do with the way I 9patch'd them.

Comment: Cool, i'm pretty busy today so i'll try and have a look at them for you later and get back to you.

Comment: I fixed this by creating the 9 patch differently: Normal toggle button: [link] (http://i.imgur.com/o20Kj.png) Pressed toggle button: [link] (http://i.imgur.com/TE4mV.png) - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Kenny!